Suppress group labels below bars in a barplot
A want a barplot without the labels beneath the bars:

I have tried names.arg = "", but it returns an error:
Error in barplot.default(stats::xtabs(mf, addNA = TRUE), horiz = horiz,  : 
  incorrect number of names

I understand that the length of names.arg should correspond to the number of bars, but I don't want to calculate that and create something like names.arg = rep("", 50).
How can I suppress those labels?

Sample data
barplot(c(x = 1))


It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What's wrong with names.arg = rep("", 50)? You just don't like it? How about xaxt="n"

If this barplot(`names<-`(1:5, paste0("G", 1:5))) is your data pls include it in your question. This way it can serve as a complete and reproducible example where ppl can use the code to generate precise answers.

@MrFlick Thank you for xaxt="n". I hadn't thought that would work, because I tried axes=FALSE, which didn't.

@MrFlick names.arg = rep("", 50) is like putting a paper bag over a lamp instead of switching it off.
